# Will lenses of a different brand work on a Nikon DSLR?

Tags: lens, nikon, dslr, compatibility, third-party

I am new to photography and I am planning to buy a Nikon D3300 (with 18–55 mm kit lens) to start with, after reading through the reviews. But one question lingering on to my mind even after reading multiple posts here is whether there is any option to buy any other lens type, of any other brand — say Canon or Sony — to fit in to this camera.

Comment: But this post talks about the old camera with new lenses.. what i am asking about is if there are other types of lenses that will fit in to the yet to be bought camera..

Comment: @newbuddy2015 The answer is still the same. It all depends on the mount type, if there is an adapter, and flange distance. And no, that post works if you want to use an old Canon 50mm f/1.8 FD on a new Canon 5D Mark III (or in my case that lens on a Rebel 2000).

Comment: Read the complete post pease. And wellcome :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is really "Are there third-party lenses which will work on the Nikon D3300?", which is only answered by the [other "possible duplicate" question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y) in passing, because it starts from the assumption of incompatible mount, when actually third-party manufacturers *do* produce Nikon-mount lenses — although Sony and Canon do not. (Sigma is the only company I am aware of which makes lenses for their own system *and* for others.)

So the basic answer is *yes* — look for lenses from Sigma, Tokina, Tamron, Voigtländer, Zeiss, Samyang, and others which are labeled as **for Nikon** or **F-mount**. Note that some of these may be manual focus only, both at the high end (Zeiss, Voigtländer) and budget end (Samyang). And also be aware that these are generally reverse-engineered for compatibility, not licensed, so for lenses which contain electronics, updates may be needed for compatibility in the future.

Comment: Footnote: Samyang lenses are manufactured by [Samyang Optics](http://www.syopt.com/en/) in Korea, but get rebranded as Rokinon, Vivitar, Falcon, Walimex, Bower, Opteka, Bell and Howell, Polar, and Pro-Optic. And "manual focus" also means "manual aperture" and non-reporting (i.e., no electronic communication).